# Send byte data to Google Cloud Speech while recording the audio using NAudio

Tags: c#, winforms, naudio, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I am creating a simple WinForms Speech-To-Text application. This application listens to the microphone using NAudio API and sends the audio to Google Cloud Speech API. When Google Cloud Speech API responds with text, I am appending that text to a TextBox. See the code below:

```
async private void WaveIn_DataAvailable(object sender, WaveInEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Factory.StartNew(()=> { WriteToTextBox(e.Buffer); }, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
}
void WriteToTextBox(byte[] bufferData)
{
    var speech = SpeechClient.Create();
    var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
    {
        Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
        SampleRateHertz = 16000,
        LanguageCode = "en",
    }, RecognitionAudio.FromBytes(bufferData));

    foreach (var result in response.Results)
    {
        foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + " " + alternative.Transcript;
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine except the thing that `response.Results` is always empty. But when I save this buffer data to a file and then call Google Cloud Speech API using following code:

```
var response = speech.Recognize(new RecognitionConfig()
            {
                Encoding = RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                SampleRateHertz = 16000,
                LanguageCode = "en",
            }, RecognitionAudio.FromFile("audio.raw"));
```

It is working fine.

Comment: In `WriteToTextBox` what is the value of `bufferData` is there actually anything in it?

Comment: @AshleyMedway yes it has the audio data.

Comment: What is the output if you before your loop you do this `Console.WriteLine(response);`?

Comment: @AshleyMedway It's displaying `{ }`

Comment: It's more like a bug report on RecognitionAudio.FromBytes(Byte[]). I have created a public issue and please follow that from now on. https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/111789680

Comment: I've only just seen this - sorry about that. [`FromFile` uses `FromBytes`](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-dotnet/blob/b912eb622efae4c4c3f3120d0a279bca5d4f8b53/apis/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1/Google.Cloud.Speech.V1/RecognitionAudioPartial.cs#L107) under the hood, and `FromBytes` is utterly trivial. I strongly suspect that the problem lies elsewhere, e.g. the timing of when you save things. Are you still facing this issue? If you could provide an easy way of reproducing it, that would make it much easier to diagnose.